# synchronize all users in keycloak

Tags: ldap, synchronization, keycloak

I have insatlled the Keycloak server and the 389-ds on an ubuntuserver20.04 on a virtualbox . For testing the connection and the authentication i have added some users and groups in 389-ds . On the server console management on keycloak works the ,, test connection,, without any error message . The ,, test authentication ,, is also working properley . But when i click on the ,, synchronize all users ,, on the keycloak under the user federation , i get the message ,, success ! sync of users finished successfully . 0 imported users , 0 updated users ,, . The users on 389-ds dont have any email or password , they are just simple users with uid and ou to test . Could you please give me any tips ? thanks :))

Comment: I might help you if you could share your current configuration. A screenshot would be enough.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry that i replayed late. It works now, thanks ;))